# Connect Jenkins-Gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

Why I can't find the "Gitlab API Token" in the dropdown? although the necessary plugins are installed
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrol.png)

Comment: Please provide more info about your installation, we can't log into your machine and look around.

Comment: Sorry, I just installed jenkins and the plugins and I configured a Toen for Gitlab that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first install the plugins required to get that.

1) [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) - For additional [Info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_git_setup.htm) for configuring and installing.

2) [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) for managing the credentials.

For the second step, in the page itself, you will be having pdf document. Please go through it and you will understand. Hope this helps.